# Divide line by length with QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, splitting, points-to-line

I'm a newbie using QGIS 2.12 and I'm trying to split a line in QGIS and place points every x meters. There is a tool in ArcGIS (divide by length add in). How to achieve this in QGIS?

Comment: You can use a tool in the processing toolbox called "densify geometries at a given interval". You can found it at Qgis geoalgorithms/vector geometry tools/densify geometries at a given interval. The tool will add nodes at the interval desired. Bear in mind to use the processing toolbox in advanced interface.

Comment: In case anyone is still looking for this like I was: There is now a 'Points along geometry' in the Processing Toolbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this requires 2 tools, both of which can be accessed from the *Processing Toolbox*:

1. *GRASS* - **v.split.length**

[image: Line example]

[image: v.split.length]

[image: Line split]

---

2. *SAGA* - **Convert Polygon/Line Vertices to Points**

[image: Convert Polygon/Line Vertices to Points]

[image: Vertices]

Comment: @Jeff - Most welcome buddy! As pointed out by others, there are other tools which you could also use (I always use the ones mentioned above).